# How to syncronize credentials in a small laboratory? (very slim alternative to ldap)

Tags: linux, scp, ldap, synchronization, shadow

We run a small lab with 20 Linux systems (RaspberryPI, NAS, Desktop PCs) for research with 4 scientists who all need sudo permissions.

We trust all 4 users as they have sudo permission and physical access any way.
The laboratory network is a local network and not accessible from the internet.

Now we would like to synchronize the credentials. If one user changes the password, it should not be changed manually on the other 19 systems.

I would like to avoid complex solutions like LDAP. The first idea which came into my mind was to maintain the credentials on the NAS as single source and copy them via scp to the clients in a systemd module.

But I guess I am reinventing the wheel and there are ready to use packages/solutions and I just tried the wrong search terms.

Which package or solution is commonly used for such a scenario?

Comment: NIS/YP? Bind/Hesiod if you can get it? Plain Kerberos? If I were you, I'd take the hit and install 389DS and possibly Kerberos.

Comment: yeah, slimmer than openldap is going to be hard, and you'd really just want a working authenitcation solution, so the usual suites would fit that.

Answer (score 1):

> Now we would like to synchronize the credentials. If one user changes the password, it should not be changed manually on the other 19 systems.

LDAP is for storing user attributes such as UID/GID or home directory; it's *not really* the first thing for storing credentials (although it can do that, sure).

My suggestion would be to set up Kerberos with e.g. MIT's krb5-kdc.

1. Install `krb5-user`, `krb5-kdc`, `krb5-admin-server` on Debian.
2. Choose a realm name (*preferably* one that corresponds to a real DNS domain name, but not strictly required; always upper-case though).
3. Do `kdb5_util create -s` to initialize the KDC database. (The `-s` makes it store the master key in a file next to the database.)
4. Run `kadmin.local` to start creating entries:

   - Add a user account: `addprinc fred`
   - Add a server: `addprinc -nokey host/fredpc.example.com`
   - Extract the keytab for a host: `ktadd -k /tmp/fredpc.keytab host/fredpc.example.com`
   - (For hosts, the part that goes after `host/` should correspond to what the host itself thinks its FQDN is, i.e. what `hostname -f` reports on that server.)
5. Start `krb5-kdc.service` and make sure the server's firewall allows inbound port 88 (TCP *and* UDP) for Kerberos requests.

(Note that you won't be defining UIDs or login shells through Kerberos – this can remain in your regular /etc/passwd and doesn't need to be identical across hosts. Kerberos can be used for authentication regardless of the account source.)

On all servers:

1. Install `krb5-user` and `libpam-krb5` on Debian.
2. When prompted, enter the realm name and the KDC hostname. (The latter could be configured through a DNS SRV record to reduce per-host steps. Both options go in /etc/krb5.conf, so it's possible to just deploy that through `scp` instead.)
3. Copy the host's keytab to `/etc/krb5.keytab` (mode 0600).

It's not entirely *simple*, but (IMHO) still simpler than LDAP.

Options:

- If you don't want to mess with PAM, OpenSSH actually has built-in support for verifying passwords against Kerberos; that's the `KerberosAuthentication` option in sshd_config. It has the same requirements (krb5.conf, krb5.keytab) as the PAM module. However, PAM also handles password changes through 'passwd', so if you don't use it then you'll need to teach users to run `kpasswd` instead.
- As a bonus, Kerberos will give you SSO – passwordless SSH from one host to another. That's the other option, `GSSAPIAuthentication`, in sshd_config. It uses tickets obtained either by pam_krb5 or manually through `kinit`. (GNOME and Windows can handle this automatically, making it as transparent as SSH keys.)